# I am having difficulty understanding this differentiation question

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

SO I have this question:

[image: differentiation question]

I think the question is asking me to do a a partial differentiation to find dx/ds, dy/ds, dz/ds which I have found in my solution, but I am not confident with the approach I took to solve this question. My solution for those are as following:

[image: My solution]

Can someone please tell me if I am on the right path and secondly the question asks to find df/ds which I am not sure how to find.

Comment: I presume you're meant to use the chain rule incorporating $x=x(s)$ etc

Comment: @Kevin how would you apply chain rule to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin said, apply the chain rule to $\phi(s) = f(x(s), y(s), z(s))$:

$\frac{d \phi}{ds}(x(s), y(s), z(s)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x(s), y(s), z(s)) \frac{dx}{ds}(s) + \ldots$